# Alternative of HttpPostedFileBase in asp.net core and name of namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to design a class that have `HttpPostedFileBase` based property like,

```
public HttpPostedFileBase picture;
```

I am using `IFormFile` and using `Microsoft.AspNet.Http`;

the Code looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;

namespace design.Model
{
    public class gallery
    {
        public IFormFile picture;
    }
}
```

and it gives an error at `using Microsoft.AspNet.Http` line. How can this be solved?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: IDE can't resolved using Microsoft.AspNet.Http....@dee zg

Comment: have you installed nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/ ?

Comment: Yes..but as it is .net core so Aspnet cannot recognized.....when I use aspnetCore it is ok. but IFormfile cannot recognized...

Comment: oh oh, didnt notice that. you should of course use http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/12/uploading-files-asp-net-core/. what is the problem when using .net core iformfile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `HttpFileBase`, you've to use `IFormFile` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` (install NuGet package if you haven't.)

Answer (score 2):

Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` from NuGet Package Manager.